# Can I view the HTML source of an email sent to an Gmail address from an Android device?

Tags: gmail, html

I have a Samsung tablet and would like to check the HTML source code from a Gmail message. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You mean, like when you use the "Show original" option in the desktop version of Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ***[Firefox Aurora for Android](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/27.0a2/auroranotes/)***; I can simply type `view-source:` in front of the address in the address bar, and a new page loads with the HTML code, etc...displayed in a formatted viewer.  I'm not sure if the other browsers have the same functionality, or what the corresponding command for those would be. You can find Firefox Aurora for Android at [their website.](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/27.0a2/auroranotes/)

There's also a [convenient Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/view-source-mobile/?src=search) that creates a menu shortcut for this function.

Comment: The question was about the source of an email, and since GMail is pretty heavily JS+Ajax-based, you (probably) can't see the source of the email itself.

Comment: I also expect that they're using the Gmail app, not a browser.

Comment: presume, we can; however, until questions are asked with more specific details, we might as well presume the OP can put the "alternative" response I provided to good use.